# Variables not retaining values in shell script block while passed through Jenkins job parameter to a Jenkins Shared Library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sh, shared-libraries

I am encountering an issue with variables not retaining their values when accessed within the sh block of the Shared Library code. Facing the problem when invoking a Shared Library from a Jenkins Job while passing arguments to the library function.

JENKINS_VERSION : 2.367

Jenkins Job code :

```
  pipeline {
      agent {
          //  The agent's details
      }
      parameters {
          // Some parameters
      }
      environment {
          WEB_ACL_NAME = "${params.WEBACLNAME}"
          WEB_ACL_SCOPE = 'CLOUDFRONT'
          // ...... Some more env
            
          }
      options {
          disableConcurrentBuilds()
      }
      stages {
          stage('Update Web ACL Configurations') {
              steps {
                  script {
                  updateWebACLConfig WEB_ACL_NAME: "${WEB_ACL_NAME}, "WEB_ACL_SCOPE: "${WEB_ACL_SCOPE}", CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE: 500, CONTENT_DATA: "{}" ,  CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY : "custom500"
              }
          }
      }
  }             
  }
```

Shared Library code (updateWebACLConfig.groovy):

```
  void call(Map map = [ : ]) {
      // ...
      String WEB_ACL_SCOPE = null;
      String WEB_ACL_NAME = null;
      String CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY = "${map.CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY}"?.trim();
      Integer CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE = ${map.CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE};
  
      log.info("CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY:$CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY")
      log.info("CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE:$CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE")
      if (map.WEB_ACL_NAME?.trim() && map.WEB_ACL_DESCRIPTION?.trim() && map.WEB_ACL_RULE_DEFAULT_ACTION?.trim() && map.WEB_ACL_SCOPE?.trim() && map.WEB_ACL_SCOPE_CLOUDFRONT_REGION?.trim() && map.STS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN?.trim() && map.WEB_ACL_RULES_JSON_FILE_PATH?.trim() && map.VC_SAMPLED_REQUESTS_ENABLED?.trim() && map.VC_CLOUD_WATCH_METRICS_ENABLED?.trim() && map.VC_METRIC_NAME?.trim()) {
          // ...
      } else {
          error("Missing required parameter: WEB_ACL_NAME, WEB_ACL_DESCRIPTION, WEB_ACL_RULE_DEFAULT_ACTION, WEB_ACL_SCOPE, WEB_ACL_SCOPE_CLOUDFRONT_REGION, STS_ASSUME_ROLE_ARN, WEB_ACL_RULES_JSON_FILE_PATH, VC_METRIC_NAME")
      }
  
      sh '''
          echo "Value Custom response body key is  $CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY"
          echo "$CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE"
          echo "Trial $WEB_ACL_SCOPE"
          echo "Name of web ACL is $WEB_ACL_NAME"
           ...
      '''
      // ...
  }
```

I have a Jenkins Job that invokes another file which is Jenkins Library. This pipeline has several fields, In the stages section Within the `script` block, It invokes the `updateWebACLConfig` library  passing multiple arguments including `WEB_ACL_NAME`, `WEB_ACL_DESCRIPTION`, and custom variables such as `CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE` and `CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY`.

In Shared Library code :
CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY and CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE hold the value provided by the Jenkins job at runtime. I have confirmed that the variables hold the correct values by using log.info().

The issue arises when accessing these variables within the `sh` block using `echo`. While the values of `WEB_ACL_SCOPE` and `WEB_ACL_NAME` are displayed correctly, the values of `CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY` and `CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE` appear blank.

I have confirmed that the variables are properly defined and assigned values before entering the `sh` block. There are no special characters or formatting issues in the variable values that could cause this discrepancy.

The Console output of it is as follows
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g2qp.png)
I would appreciate any assistance or insights on how to resolve this issue. Thank you for your support.

Comment: you should use triple quote `"""` to wrap the bash in `sh` step,  https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

WEB_ACL_SCOPE and WEB_ACL_NAME are environment variables, CUSTOM_RESPONSE_CODE and CUSTOM_RESPONSE_BODY_KEY are groovy variables.

Jenkins tries to resolve groovy variables if the shell uses double quotes, or triple double quotes in your case.